# How to install numpy on windows?

Tags: python, numpy

Just started learning python during Covid, and currently having some issues getting numpy to work for the first time (windows 10).

installed it (1.19.1)and matplotlib (3.3.0)on pip

```
C:\Users\davel>pip install numpy
Requirement already satisfied: numpy in c:\users\davel\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages (1.19.1)

C:\Users\davel>pip install matplotlib
Requirement already satisfied: matplotlib in c:\users\davel\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages (3.3.0)
```

when trying to run a simple test program in IDLE(3.8-32 bit),

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.linspace(0, 3, 20)
y = np.linspace(0, 9, 20)
plt.plot(x, y)
plt.plot(x, y, 'o')
plt.show()
```

I get:

```
    ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numpy.core'; 'numpy' is not a package
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\davel\Desktop\Python\Test Code\numpy1.py", line 1, in <module>
    import numpy as np
  File "C:\Users\davel\Desktop\Python\Test Code\numpy.py", line 2, in <module>
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
  File "C:\Users\davel\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\__init__.py", line 174, in <module>
    _check_versions()
  File "C:\Users\davel\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\__init__.py", line 159, in _check_versions
    from . import ft2font
ImportError: numpy.core.multiarray failed to import
```

I've taken a look through various help files, and other questions, tried reinstalling, but nothing seems to help... any suggestions?  Seems to be a version compatibility error?

Thanks everyone!

EDIT:

thanks a lot for the quick reply.  I had realized that before, thought i had changed the file name, only to realize that it saved a new copy, and did not delete numpy.py.  working after a reinstall now:)

Comment: Not an answer, but install Anaconda, you will save yourself a lot of trouble.

Comment: I would recommend installing python using anaconda. The Anaconda installer contains most of commonly used packages, and you can just focus on learning the language instead!

Comment: @SayandipDutta please don't suggest installing Anaconda just because a file had a wrong name. Anaconda brings with it a whole slew of new problems

Comment: @Comos File  please don't suggest installing Anaconda just because a file had a wrong name. Anaconda brings with it a whole slew of new problems

Comment: @DeepSpace Personally, I have never had problems with Anaconda, and I think this is the recommended way to get started with python, particularly since installing packages is two steps beyond learning to code in my opinion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's take a look at your stacktrace to see what is happening:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numpy.core'; 'numpy' is not a package
```

Okay, apparently `numpy.core` was not found. Note though that `numpy` itself *was* found, but it is not a package (which means it has no "submodules" like `numpy.core`).

```
File "C:\Users\davel\Desktop\Python\Test Code\numpy1.py", line 1, in <module>
    import numpy as np
```

You're importing numpy, which seems reasonable. What happens next?

```
File "C:\Users\davel\Desktop\Python\Test Code\numpy.py", line 2, in <module>
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

You have imported `numpy`, and it is located at `"C:\Users\davel\Desktop\Python\Test Code\numpy.py"`. Note though that this is not the numpy package you're looking for, you have imported your own file which is named numpy!

The solution to your problem is to rename your file `numpy.py` to something else. When python tries to find the module, it first looks at the files in the current directory, and if it finds a numpy it happily imports it. This is also known as "shadowing".

Answer (score 1):

`"C:\Users\davel\Desktop\Python\Test Code\numpy.py"`

Rename your file to something other than `numpy.py`. When you are doing `import numpy` from a file called `numpy.py`, it imports itself.